# Коммит транзакции после выключения программы

Tags: delphi, interbase

Здравствуйте.

Получаю доступ к БД interbase через IBX. Использую один компонент `IBTransaction`. На форму вывожу все в грид и пару тестовых полей.

Вопрос: почему транзакция коммитится только после выключения проги? Если вношу изменения в поля таблицы, то пока прогу не закрою - не увижу изменения в том же `IBExpert`. Как сделать, чтобы изменения вносились сразу?

```
procedure TmainDataModule.IBCatAfterPost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
   If IBTransaction1.InTransaction then
      IBTransaction1.Commit;
end;
```

Не помогает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В свойствах IBTransaction: AutoStopAction - saCommit

1. Выполняешь запрос
2. IBTransaction.Commit;
3. потом, если используешь IBQuery, и они отключаются, заного их включаешь 
       IBQuery.Active:= True;